# Background image repeat from center to right

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am looking for a way to horizontally repeat simple color background stripe, but only from the center of the page to the right. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: jsfiddle example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to achieve this but not impossible, you can use CSS `:after` pseudo to do so.

Here, I am using `:after` pseudo element, and than we are using CSS Positioning technique to position the element 50% from the *left* and than with the *negative* `z-index` we push that to the back.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvd3r/2/)</kbd>

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://virgo.unive.it/itadict/search/images/bullet.png);
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
}
```